# IIS rejects 'Content-Type': application/json' requests

Tags: json, iis

I have a working application where I am posting to webservices using `Content-Type': application/json`. I am moving this application to another web that is also on my local machine. My new web is not working though. I am getting 401 error when requesting data. I have found that if I use `Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then I get data although not in a json format. What can possibly cause this 401 error?

Comment: what version of IIS you are using on old server and on new server?

Comment: The server is the same. But I figured it out. My webservce class wasn't marked as [ScriptService].